# Dockerize CI installation on master node VM

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

Carrying on from [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/what-os-should-a-master-node-ci-virtual-machine-be) question, would you want to dockerise your CI (Gitlab (especially if Gitlab also contains all your repositories) or Jenkins) installation on your master node virtual machine?

What are the advantages and disadvantages to this, than just installing normally onto the VM without docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pros**

- possible to run the CI on a container orchestration platform

**Cons**

- docker in docker in docker

Comment: The poster didn't make mention of having executors on master.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just the master, I would say it's okay. The main concern would be any recursive dependencies where your CI tool manages the Docker platform that it runs on.

Build agents are another case. I've run CI with Docker in both configurations, and I prefer running outside of Docker and invoking it during your build, as it allows consistency between your dev and CI platform. Eg: https://github.com/amaysim-au/docker-serverless